# Initial load of UIView not from segue

Tags: ios, ios6, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, segue

I am using [ECSlidingViewController](https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController) with two view controllers. The 'detail' view is shown on initial load, a button on the 'detail' view menubar then shows the 'master' view which is a UITableView, much like the Path and Facebook UI's.

My problem is I want to load this detail view when the app starts. This will then add some initial data into my Core Data database and display a row in the master view's UITableView.

If I display the master view and select a row in the menu I perform a segue to the detail page which then loads the data correctly using prepareForSegue:sender.

How can I perform a task in the detail view ONLY on that initial load and not when loaded via the segue?

**Background Info**

My first view in the StoryBoard  loads both the master and detail views:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Setup the view controllers
    self.topViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainTop"];
    self.underLeftViewController  = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Menu"];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
    - (void) awakeFromNib
    {
        //initialisation code here
    }
```

This is only called when the scene is first unarchived from the storyboard file.

If that doesn't do the trick, you could use an 'initialised' boolean property which you set to TRUE after your code is first run.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping for a solid solution that I might have missed from the docs to differentiate when a UIViewController was created by a segue or not.

Comment: @JMWhittaker - i am fairly certain there is nothing in the API. Set an `arrivedFromSegue` flag via `prepareForSegue` or write a custom Segue that does the same?

Comment: Thanks @He Was, I can't find anything in the docs either about this. Your suggestion is fine and setting a flag would work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can present master view modally, instead of segueing.

Comment: Presenting the master view isn't the problem here. It presents fine. What I want is to run a method on the first load only and not when loaded using a segue.